# My snowflake azure seems to be reloading files when the AWS doesn't

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the files in S3 because Microsoft's storage is too complicated for me to deal with, but am using an azure version of Snowflake.  Every time I run the load process it loads every file that I have.  The AWS version of snowflake doesn't do that.  It keeps track of the file names tht I've already loaded and doesn't load them.  What's going on?

here is an example of one that I am loading through a procedure:

```
var stmt1 =  snowflake.execute( { sqlText:
`
copy into dw_order_charges
from @dw_order_charges
file_format = load_format_pipe
`
} );
```

Thanks,  --sw

Comment: Both the Azure and AWS versions of Snowflake will track files that have already been loaded.  Either the files are being reloaded to S3 or there is an issue with Snowflake.  I recommend you open a Snowflake Support ticket for them to investigate.

Comment: Yes, as Mike mentioned, they should behave similarly.